# Node.js get mysql data and append to object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, server, node-mysql

I am trying to get data from a MySQL database using node.js. Then I want to append that data to an object so I can later use it to make an HTML table.

This is my module code:

```js
var mysql = require("mysql");
var date = require("dateformat");
var results = {}

exports.data = function () 
{
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "admin",
    password: "myphpadmin",
    database: "tests"
});

conn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.query("SELECT Id, Description, Date, Amount, Merchant, Type, Sub, Source  FROM main", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else append(result);
    });
});



function append(result) {
    for (i = 0; i > result.length; i++) {
        id = result[i].Id;
        des = result[i].Description;
        date = dateFormat(result[i].Date, "mmmm d, yyyy");
        a = result[i].Amount;
        m = result[i].Merchant;
        t = result[i].Type;
        sub = result[i].Sub;
        s = result[i].Source;
    data = {"Id": id, "Des": des, "Date": date, "A": a, "M": m, "T": t, "Sub": sub,"S": s}
        results.push(data)
    }
}


return results
}
```

This is my main file which I run...

```js
var data = require('./data')

console.log(data.data())
```

When I run:

`node tests.js`

it shows: `{}`

Any idea why?

I am using Node.js(Version: 14.15.4) on a windows 10 computer. I can give more details if needed!

Comment: Results isn't an array so I doubt that .push will work. Try spreading the data into it instead: results { ...data }

Comment: @anatolhiman I don't understand... Wouldn't that replace the previous contents?

Comment: This question shouldn't have been closed because there's a bug in the code that we could help you with. If you spread the new object 'data' into the 'results' object (I assume your database gives you an object and not an array), the end result would be the full object you want, if 'data' had been valid. It's now invalid because it uses undefined variables. 'id', 'des', 'date' etc. aren't initiated with const or let. You could have gotten each value into 'data' directly without all the variables, like this: data={'Id': result[i].id etc. etc.}.

Comment: Once your 'data' object is OK and you spread it into the empty object 'results' with `results = { ...data }` you have completed your first round in the loop. But you want to avoid that the next rounds of the loop overwrites the data from the previous. One way is to save each round as a new object with a unique name. You can do that by including the start 'results' object inside the loop and assigning the iterator [i] to it so you get results1, results2, results3, etc. and thus avoid overwriting anything. Afterwards you take each object and insert separately into your table.

Comment: @anatolhiman Here is an idea of what it gives me... I think it is an array: [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/dHtaUUE); could you please explain what you mean with a code sample?

Comment: @anatolhiman actually never mind... I used a for/in the loop and made results an array. It works now. Thanks for trying!